# File search from a folder from FileCabinet in NetStuite returns only five records?

Tags: netsuite

When I am doing the search, the results always contain only five records (in ascending order). I need to get a list of all files in the folder. What am I doing wrong?

```
FileSearch fileSearch = new FileSearch();
FileSearchBasic fileSearchBasic = new FileSearchBasic();

// Specify the folder in which the search is to be done.
SearchMultiSelectField folderFilter = new SearchMultiSelectField
{
    @operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
    operatorSpecified = true
};

RecordRef[] folder = new RecordRef[1];
folder[0] = new RecordRef
{
    // Internal id of the folder where pospay files are stored.                
    internalId = ns.DataCollection["netSuite:PositivePayFolderInternalId"]
};

folderFilter.searchValue = folder;
fileSearchBasic.folder = folderFilter;
fileSearch.basic = fileSearchBasic;            

var result = NSBase.Client.Service.search(fileSearch);
var recordList = result.recordList; // this has ony five results, why?
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, 'PageSize' was set to 5 in the service client's constructor.